# How do I remove the horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

So i have been having some trouble with the horizontal scroll bar. Could someone tell me how to remove it? I have searched another answers and I got this:

```
overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
```

But I don't know how I apply it. Do I have to assign it to a class and then the class to a div tag? What exactly do I do? 
A answer would really be appreciated.

Comment: Showing us the HTML and CSS or the page on which you wish to achieve this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to prevent the horizontal scroll bar on the entire page. If so:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: heh, the funny thing is I did what you typed but it helped me solve my other problem. It did not remove the horizontal bar. One of my link got positioned which was not happenign before

Comment: Now it removed the horizontal bar too. The solutions other people suggested to do it with the div tag didn't work. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary to assign it to a class.

There might be two ways to do it.

Way 1:

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden">
```

Way 2:

Just create a class in css:

```
.divstyle{
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden
}
```

and then assign that class to div like:

```
<div class="divstyle"></div>
```

Both will work well... :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the `overflow-x:hidden;`  in CSS with the DIV, or whatever element, that has the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

add this to a class and add that class to a div

```
.YourClass{overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;}
```